# Нажатие за пределы View(EditText)

Tags: java, android, click, edittext, butterknife

Нужно сделать так, чтобы программа понимала, что пользователь нажал на ЛЮБОЕ место экрана за пределами editText.

Я использую аннотацию @OnFocusChange библиотеки ButterKnife.

Этот метод с аннотацией вызывается, когда пользователь нажимает на нужный EditText или на любую другую View, если мой EditText был в фокусе.

Если я нажимаю на пустое место экрана, то метод не вызывается.

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы метод срабатывал не только при выборе другого View, но и при нажатии просто за пределы данного EditText.

```
@OnFocusChange(R.id.editText){
public void OnFocusChangeEditText(){
    if (editText.hasFocus()){
    //...
    }
    else{
    //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил данную проблему таким способом: вместо метода по изменению фокуса использовал обычный onTouch

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    //...
    return false;
}
```

в котором обрабатывал нажатие на все элементы экрана(при нажатии на любой элемент возвращал изначальный размер всех остальных элементов). Выглядит как костыль, потому что надо все элементы добавлять вручную, но для активити с маленьким кол-вом элементов сгодится. Если элементов много, то данное решение можно считать нецелесообразным.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы обрабатывать любые клики по экрану в `Android` существуют два метода: `onTouchEvent` и `onInterceptTouchEvent`. Все они доступны для любого `View`. 
Если вы хотите обработать клик по экрану, вы можете переопределить метод `onTouchEvent(view: View, event: MotionEvent)`. `Event` содержит координаты касания, а также тип касания (палец опущен на экран, палец двигается по экрану, палец оторвался от экрана)